# android 4.4 apps how to configure statusbar

Tags: android, statusbar, configure, android-4.4-kitkat

In android 4.4 there is a function in class com.android.systemui.statusbar.SystemBars

```
private void createStatusBarFromConfig() {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "createStatusBarFromConfig");
    final String clsName = mContext.getString(R.string.config_statusBarComponent);
    if (clsName == null || clsName.length() == 0) {
        throw andLog("No status bar component configured", null);
    }
    Class<?> cls = null;
    try {
        cls = mContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(clsName);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw andLog("Error loading status bar component: " + clsName, t);
    }
    try {
        mStatusBar = (BaseStatusBar) cls.newInstance();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw andLog("Error creating status bar component: " + clsName, t);
    }
    mStatusBar.mContext = mContext;
    mStatusBar.mComponents = mComponents;
    mStatusBar.start();
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "started " + mStatusBar.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

You can configure statusbar in this function.

My App need to configure my customized status bar.But I don.t know how to change statusbar in my activity codes.

Comment: What do you want to change? color?

Comment: color,icon...I want repalce the whole statusbar

Comment: You can try to dig around this libary an see how they achieve their colouring of the statusbar? https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint